# Highcharts img in html title; onerror doesn't fire even with Highcharts Security AST set

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need the onerror function of an img to run if the src of an image can't be found in highcharts titles / text.

However, highcharts doesn't support onerror for img's out of the box and I need to add it to the safe list as outlined [in the docs](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/security).

E.g.

```
title: {
    useHTML:true,
    text: '<img src="/A/NotFound/src.png" onerror="doSomething(this)" />Solar Employment Growth'
}
```

I've tried setting the AST to allow the attribute;

```
Highcharts.AST.allowedAttributes.push('onerror');
```

However, as can be seen in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattscotty/9h7su4gp/), the function does not run.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is not fired because there is no `src` attribute on the element. Add the below code to allow using `src` with an empty string reference.

```
Highcharts.AST.allowedAttributes.push('onerror');
Highcharts.AST.allowedAttributes.push('src');
Highcharts.AST.allowedReferences.push('');
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aocsn5p4/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting

Comment: Excellent, that's worked, thanks.
For posterity, is there a way of stating only certain tags can use these attributes (i.e. lockdown onerror to img's only)?

Comment: Hi @Matt Scott, It seems that there is no such possibility for now, but you can wrap/overwrite the default `AST.filterUserAttributes` method.